# Unable to access ECR from Azure using IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecr

I am trying to access ECR from Azurem I created an IAM role with access key and IAM policy.
I am getting the error as "no identity-based policy allows the ecr:GetAuthorizationToken action"

```json
 {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecr:GetRegistryPolicy",
        "ecr:DescribeRegistry",
        "ecr:DescribePullThroughCacheRules",
        "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        "ecr:PutRegistryScanningConfiguration",
        "ecr:DeleteRegistryPolicy",
        "ecr:CreatePullThroughCacheRule",
        "ecr:DeletePullThroughCacheRule",
        "ecr:PutRegistryPolicy",
        "ecr:GetRegistryScanningConfiguration",
        "ecr:PutReplicationConfiguration",
        "ecr:PutLifecyclePolicy",
        "ecr:PutImageTagMutability",
        "ecr:StartImageScan",
        "ecr:CreateRepository",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:PutImageScanningConfiguration",
        "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
        "ecr:PutImage",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
        "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
        "ecr:StartLifecyclePolicyPreview",
        "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:region: account:repository/reponame/*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```